# Expected value of sum of cards

Tags: probability

If each card on a regular 52 deck card has points that corresponds to their number (like 2 of hearts is 2 points, 7 of clubs is 7 points), the Jack, Queen, King each being 10 points and you keep drawing without replacement until sum of all points is 10 or more....what's the mean of sum of points?

Comment: By expected value, do you mean the expected number of cards for the sum to exceed $10$?  Is an Ace worth $1$?

Comment: Are you asking what the expected sum of points is, conditioned on "getting a sum of $10$ or more?"  How many cards are involved?

Comment: I just edited the question...I need to know the expected value of sum of all the points greater than or equal to 10. I would keep drawing cards from deck until my total is 10 or more.

Comment: This seems a bit tricky to get an exact answer to but simulation would be easy.  Do you need an exact answer or just an approximate one?

Comment: Please note that you have simultaneously posted this question on Cross Validated.